# Trying to pass a matrix by reference

Tags: c

Sorry i am new to c, i am trying to pass this matrix to a procedure by reference
so i don't have to copy it in memory. I couldn't find any explanation. This is the closest i could get but it doesn't work.
The point of the program is only for that, i made it to test it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int tmatrix[5][5];

void print (tmatrix*mtr)
{

    int l , m;  

    l=0;

    while (l<=4)

    {
        m=0;

        while (m<=4)
        {
            printf("%d", *mtr[l][m]);

            m = m+1;
        }

        printf("\n");

        l=l+1;

    }
}
//-----------------------------------
int main()
{
int i , j;

tmatrix matrix;


i=0;

while (i <= 4)
{

    j=0;

    while (j<=4)
    {

        matrix[i][j] = 3;

        j = j+1;

    }

    i = i+1;

}

print(&matrix);

return 0;

}
```

It should print:

```
33333
33333
33333
33333
33333
```

But it prints:

```
33333
54198992041990930
1977890592-1961670060002752492
03232520
664-21479789407743168
```

I know it may be something to do with the pointers because i think those are addresses, but i got no clues.

Comment: The expression `*mtr[l][m]` does not do what you think it does because of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: You also have to remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, so there's no need to pass arrays by reference (or rather *emulate* passing by reference, since C doesn't have it).

Comment: Thank you very much guys , i've been stuck with this for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. matrix is a 2D array of integers. You can directly pass it to the function. Passing an array will be the same as passing it by reference.
2. The `printf` inside the function will also be changed to directly access it. `*mtr[l][m] --> mtr[l][m]`
3. While calling it, you can call it directly as shown.  `print(&matrix) --> print(matrix)`

The modified code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int tmatrix[5][5];

void print (tmatrix mtr)
{

    int l , m;  

    l=0;

    while (l<=4)

    {
        m=0;

        while (m<=4)
        {
            printf("%d", mtr[l][m]);

            m = m+1;
        }

        printf("\n");

        l=l+1;

    }
}
//-----------------------------------
int main()
{
int i , j;

tmatrix matrix;


i=0;

while (i <= 4)
{

    j=0;

    while (j<=4)
    {

        matrix[i][j] = 3;

        j = j+1;

    }

    i = i+1;

}

print(matrix);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rishikesh Raje. But can i ask you, what if i want to pass it by value?

Comment: @NicoBaldelli in C, arrays are always passed by reference. You cannot pass it by value.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje, wrong, all is passed by value in C, but an array decays into a pointer

Comment: So, effectively, you cannot pass an array by value, right?

Comment: Not directly, the only way is embedding the array into a `struct` and passing a pointer to this `struct`